# TestStartup.cs not working as Startup.cs in .NET Core functional tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

Im working on functional testing with my `WebApi` project.

In my `Startup.cs` i have registered service, `Mediatr`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilterAttribute)))
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddMediatR(new CreateUserCommand().GetType().Assembly);

        //and other services
    }
}
```

This `Startup` is default from my `Api` project.

To functional testing my app, i made `TestStartup.cs` class:

```
public class TestStartup
{
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilterAttribute)))
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddMediatR(typeof(ConfirmReservationCommand.Handler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        //and ofc, other services
    }
}
```

My question is, why when i pass `TestStartup.cs` (that exisiting in `Tests.csproj`, not in `Api.csproj` as `Startup.cs`) `Mediatr` cant be registered properly (I get `Internal Server Error 500`), but when i pass `Startup.cs` into my fixture, everything works ok?

my `Test`:

```
public class ReservationControllerTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public ReservationControllerTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<TestStartup> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Server_Should_Return_Reservation_List()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/Reservation");

        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var reservations = json.DeserializeObjectFromJson<ReservationsListViewModel>();

        // when i pass Startup: Code 200OK, When i pass TestStartup: Error 500
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        reservations.ShouldBeOfType<ReservationsListViewModel>();
        reservations.Reservations.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
    }
}
```

My `CustomWebApplicationFactory` Looks like this:

```
ublic class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                //getting context and data seeding
            }
        });

        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }

    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TStartup>();
    }
```

Thanks for any advice

**EDIT:**

Exception message and strack trace:

```
    stackTrace: "   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerBase.GetHandler[THandler](ServiceFactory factory)
   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Handle>g__Handler|0()
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
   at SSPark.Api.Controllers.ReservationController.GetAllReservations() in C:\Users\Michał\source\repos\ss\Controllers\ReservationController.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()"
message: "Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[SSPark.Application.Reservation.Query.GetAllReservationsQuery,SSPark.Application.Reservation.Query.ReservationsListViewModel]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples."
```

Comment: I think there must be some hints in the output console. Try to check the log.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me, how to trigger console in tests?

Comment: @tia i added stack trace and exception message

Comment: It really looks like some dependencies are not registered properly, but it's strange that it doesn't report exactly what is missing.

Comment: Normal `Startup.cs` works great in testing. I copy-pasted `Mediatr` service registration to `TestStartup.cs` and it not work

Comment: I cant find out where `Startup.cs` is special. I change class name to `Startup` in `TestStartup.cs` and it not work too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type param for `WebApplicationFactory` is `TEntryPoint`. It's used to indicate the assembly of your application, not which "Startup" class is utilized. In other words, it could just as easily be `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` or even `WebApplicationFactory<Foo>`, where `Foo` is simply a random class in your application. The actual "Startup" class is specified via `UseStartup`.

Using `Startup` is the conventional approach, though, so you should keep it as `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`, where `Startup` is a reference to the SUT's `Startup` class, and then when setting up the factory you do:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseStartup<TestStartup>();
```

Comment: Hi Chriss, thanks for your attention! I Already do this, what you mentioned in your answer. im using `.UseStartup<TStartup>();` in my `CustomWebApplicationFactoryClass`. Look on the overriden method on bottom :)

Comment: Then, look at my `fixture` in test method. Im passing to my `CustomWebAppFactory` `TestStartup.cs`. The problem is, that registered `MediatR` in `TestStartup` wont work, but when i passing `Startup.cs` it works great. Im trying figured out, whats wrong with `TestStartup`, and why `Startup` is good?

Comment: Yes. But, you're *also* using `TStartup` as the type param for `WebApplicationFactory`. That type param needs to be `Startup` and the `UseStartup` type param needs to be `TestStartup`, i.e. *not* the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand. When i pass to my `WebAppFactory` Tstartup as `TestStartup`, the same `TestStartup` will be used in `UserStartup()`, becuase i passed `TestStartup` as `TStartup` into my class. So, why when i pass `TStartup` as `Startup.cs` everything works fine, but when i use my custom `TestStartup` with the same (almost) services (in this case, `MediatR`), my test dont work (http500 from client) but from `Startup.cs` im getting http200?